# protobuf-net faulty enum exception (issue 422) need a good workaround

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I am working in a project that uses ProtoBuf in different languages among them .NET. For .NET we use protobuf-net.
We have extended enums and they work on the other platforms but in .NET we get a exception when trying to de-serialize.
When googling this i found this [Issue 422](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=422).
Does anyone have a good workaround or know what to download and compile for a local fix. We would prefer not to introduce weird extra enums or other weird stuff that goes against the Protobuf definition.

Comment: The link you provided has a fix you can implement it seems

Comment: @Thewads, i have downloaded the source from github and have implemented the change, but we would prefer to not release our own version, if there is another way to go about this.